# Rewriting SQL to JOINS instead of subqueries

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subquery

I have some troubles re-writing this query to using joins instead of the two subqueries. I have a problem untangling it, if you know what i mean.

```
SELECT o.order_id, n.title, c.first_name, t1.name, o.product_id,
    (SELECT ttd2.tid FROM term_data ttd2, term_node ttn2 WHERE ttd2.vid = 5 AND ttn2.nid = p.nid AND ttd2.tid=ttn2.tid) AS tid,
    (SELECT ttd4.name FROM term_data ttd4, term_node ttn4 WHERE ttd4.vid = 8 AND ttn4.nid = p.nid AND ttd4.tid=ttn4.tid) AS month
    FROM orders o, products p, node n, customers c, term_data t1, term_node t2
    WHERE o.product_id = p.nid
    AND p.nid = n.nid
    AND o.customer_email = c.customer_email
    AND t2.tid = t1.tid
    AND t1.vid = 6
    AND n.nid = t2.nid
```

Can you help? Or give some clues/hints.

Comment: There is no relationship between your main clause tables and the subquery tables - is this intended?

Comment: @Roopesh Shenoy, actually there is, but you have to use the scroll bar to see it.

Comment: yep you are right, i missed the 'p'. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite it using [ANSI SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) syntax (i.e., using JOIN and ON clauses), and it should be much more clear.

Right now all of your `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses are mixed together, so it is not easy to see the relationships. Subqueries are not necessarily a problem; this should become more clear once the syntax is cleaned up.

Comment: (Pedantic point:) Aside from the reserved word 'Month', the code in the question is already SQL-92 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule:

Move your `SELECT`ed columns up to the main `SELECT` statement, move your `FROM` clause to a `JOIN` clause below the original `FROM`, and your join condition to that line as well.  Your `WHERE` clause can stay as is.

Also as @RedFilter says, use `JOIN` and `ON` clauses.  I think you are doing cartesians but I'm not sure due to the syntax.

For example (I don't know if this is valid for your table structure since you don't give it):

```
SELECT o.order_id, n.title, c.first_name, t1.name, o.product_id,ttd2.tid as 'tid', ttd4.name as 'name'
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN products p ON o.product_id = p.nid
INNER JOIN node n ON AND p.nid = n.nid
INNER JOIN customers c ON o.customer_email = c.customer_email
INNER JOIN term_data t1 ON t2.tid = t1.tid
INNER JOIN term_node t2 ON n.nid = t2.nid 
INNER JOIN ...
WHERE n.nid = t2.nid
AND ttd2.vid = 5 
AND ttn2.nid = p.nid 
AND ttd2.tid=ttn2.tid)
AND t1.vid = 6
AND ...
```

Comment: I see! That makes a nice distinction between relations and where-clauses. What do you mean by cartesians?

Comment: A cartesian `JOIN` is a product...basically every possible combination of your tables is given.  So, if you have 4 rows in table A and 4 rows in table B, your "product" will be 16 rows (every row in A paired with every row in B, 4x4).  It's always better to use explicit joins with the syntax above because it is MUCH easier to figure out relationships and tweak if you get unexpected results.

Comment: I would explicitly use `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc., so that you know whether you have the necessary `ON` and `WHERE` clauses. Otherwise, it is just implied, and thus harder to tell when there is an error or omission.

Comment: The current problem with the above query was when the subqueries failed, because of not enough information they would just not return anything. They would also not return anything when a reference to a costumer wasn't in the database for some odd reason.

Comment: I work with very inconsistent data, and it bugs me a lot. I think i will try to rewrite my queries to match your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help.  Standardization is your friend if things are inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Rewritten to use ANSI-92 SQL and slightly simplified to remove redundant joins, your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT o.order_id, 
       n.title, 
       c.first_name, 
       tdv6.name, 
       o.product_id,
       tdv5.tid,
       tdv8.name    month
FROM orders o
     join products p           on o.product_id = p.nid
     join node n               on p.nid = n.nid
     join customers c          on o.customer_email = c.customer_email
     join term_node tnv        on n.nid = tn.nid
     join term_data tdv6       on tn.tid = tdv6.tid AND tdv6.vid = 6
     left join term_data tdv5  on tn.tid = tdv5.tid AND tdv5.vid = 5
     left join term_data tdv8  on tn.tid = tdv8.tid AND tdv8.vid = 8
```

Comment: Both sub-queries joined to `term_node` - however, there was already an inner join to `term_node` in the main query. Since the join criteria are effectively identical (from nid of products or node - which are inner joined to each other on nid and will therefore always have the same nid value), `term_node` needs to be accessed only once - unlike `term_data`, which has three different join criteria.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `SELECT DISTINCT...` ?

Comment: (Pedantic point:) Use of the the reserved word 'Month' violates SQL-92.

Comment: @onedaywhen - I'm positive it shouldn't be `SELECT DISTINCT` - with the exception of the last two `term_data` joins, this query is functionally identical to the original query (which doesn't use `DISTINCT`), while the last two joins are the equivalent of the sub-queries. Each of those in the original should only return one value (otherwise the whole query would fail) - if they do return more than one value each, then all values returned should be displayed.