# Is there a way to improve this query? Joining subquery with itself

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, subquery

I'm working with Wordpress and MySQL, and i have the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
FROM wp_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t1
       ON t1.post_id = p.ID
         AND t1.meta_key = 'followers_count' 
    LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT tt.term_id,tr.object_id
        FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
          INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
             ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
               AND tt.taxonomy='paises'
       ) as terms
         ON p.ID=terms.object_id 
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT meta_value,tt.term_id
         FROM wp_postmeta AS t1 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr
             ON t1.post_id=tr.object_id
          INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
             ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
               AND tt.taxonomy='paises'
         WHERE t1.post_id = 80
            AND t1.meta_key = 'followers_count'
       ) AS f
          ON p.post_type='post'
             AND p.post_status='publish'
             AND t1.meta_value>f.meta_value
             AND terms.term_id=f.term_id
```

Basically what i'm doing here is get the post country from the term tables, and followers_count from the wp_postmeta table. So we have 4 join tables.

And i want to get the rank of that post in the specified country using the followers_count, that's the last subquery.

It works now, but i feel like it could be improved because i'm selecting all posts with their corresponding countries and followers, then again i query the same tables to get the country and number of followers from the post i choose (80 in this case) so i limit the first query to only that country.

I tried temporary tables but i can't use it more than once in the same query and CTE doesn't exist in MySQL, so i did this.

Is there a way to improve this or shrink the query a little, more than performance i want to learn a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just after learning then I'd start by turning all the sub-selects into joins. Take a look at the output of 'explain extended' and see what the optimizer does with this query - then repeat it as a series of joins. Usually it's faster and easier to deal with if you don't use sub-selects.

Several references:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-subquery)
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856164/sql-joins-vs-sql-subqueries-performance?lq=1)
[and Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144645/rewriting-sql-to-joins-instead-of-subqueries?rq=1)

Note - this isn't a 100% rule - your mileage may vary.